# What does the command option '-range=N' do?

Tags: range, command

I can't understand the vim help for `:command-range`, it states

```
    -range=N    A count (default N) which is specified in the line
            number position (like :split); allows for zero line
            number.
```

The documentation for `:split` is not helpful either. I'd also like to know the meaning of `-range=0` if not obvious from the description of `-range=N`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `-range` flag when defining a user-command usually allows the user to provide a range to the command:

```
command -range Mine echo <range> <line1> ',' <line2>
%Mine
1,/bar/Mine
" the next one is equivalent to .Mine by default
Mine
```

However, sometimes you want to be able to do

```
0Mine
```

Or else use the number provided as a `<count>`:

```
command! -range=1 Mine echo <count>
```

You can also use the `-count` attribute for this, though then the count is allowed to come as the first argument or in the range position.

See this paragraph:

```
Range handling ~
                *E177* *E178* *:command-range* *:command-count*
By default, user-defined commands do not accept a line number range.  However,
it is possible to specify that the command does take a range (the -range
attribute), or that it takes an arbitrary count value, either in the line
number position (-range=N, like the |:split| command) or as a "count"
argument (-count=N, like the |:Next| command).  The count will then be
available in the argument with |<count>|.

Possible attributes are:

    -range      Range allowed, default is current line
    -range=%    Range allowed, default is whole file (1,$)
    -range=N    A count (default N) which is specified in the line
            number position (like |:split|); allows for zero line
            number.
    -count=N    A count (default N) which is specified either in the line
            number position, or as an initial argument (like |:Next|).
    -count      acts like -count=0

Note that -range=N and -count=N are mutually exclusive - only one should be
specified.
```

---

Re: `:split`, there's something easy to miss in this line from the docs:

```
:[N]sp[lit] [++opt] [+cmd] [file]            *:sp* *:split*
```

That sneaky little `[N]` is what indicates a count can be given as a range (usually, `N` is used for counts and `[range]` for ranges).

Then later, we read

```
        Make the new window N high (default is to use half the height
        of the current window).  Reduces the current window height to
        create room (and others, if the 'equalalways' option is set,
        'eadirection' isn't "hor", and one of them is higher than the
        current or the new window).
```

So the count in this case is used to set the window-height, à la `:10split`

Comment: Great answer! From the OP: *"The documentation for `:split` is not helpful either."* So maybe you should address how you can use `:10split` to create a new window 10 lines high? And perhaps highlight the <code>:<b>[N]</b>split</code> in the help for `:split` that illustrates that use?

Comment: The command `command -range Mine echo <range> <line1>,<line2>` is not working for me I think updating to `command -range Mine echo <range> <line1> <line2>` would make it correct.

Comment: Could you also explain why there are 2 ways to set a count `-range=N` and `-count=N`?

Comment: @PiersyP I think I did—`-range` only allows the count in range position, while `-count` also allows it as the first argument (e.g., `command! -count Mine echo <count>`, then `:123Mine` is the same as `:Mine 123`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks. I understand the difference between the 2 ways to set the count.  and the effect it has. I'm still not sure why the designers of vim would allow 2 different ways to set the count. It seems to be something that would lead to confusion?